# How to encode categorical predictor values?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, jupyter-notebook

How can I encode the Y values? This is the BILL_CODE_DESC column.

[image]

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
%matplotlib inline

df = pd.read_excel('XXXXXXXXXX')

enc = OneHotEncoder
X = df[df.columns[1:]]
Y = df[df.columns[0]]
enc.fit(Y)
```

I get this error:

TypeError: fit() missing 1 required positional argument: 'X'

**Update #1**

This code worked:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
%matplotlib inline

df = pd.read_excel('xxxxxxxxx.xlsx')

enc = LabelEncoder()

X = df[df.columns[1:]]
Y = df[df.columns[0]].values.ravel()
Y2 = enc.fit_transform(Y)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of problems:

1. You did not instanciate the encoder;
2. Fitting the encoder does not transform your data;
3. You are not using the right encoder for text data;

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder()
%matplotlib inline

df = pd.read_excel('XXXXXXXXXX')

category_encoder = LabelEncoder()  # <--- instanciate the right encoder

X = df[df.columns[1:]]
Y = df[df.columns[0]]

enc.fit_transform(Y)   # <--- this will fit and transform the data
```

Comment: thanks for the help. Had to reshape the data as well, but this helped. As i print Y the values appeared unchanged. Any thoughts? thanks

Comment: array([['SOLD EQUIPMENT'],
       ['SOLD EQUIPMENT'],
       ['SOLD EQUIPMENT'],
       ...,
       ['COMPANY OWNED'],
       ['COMPANY OWNED'],
       ['COMPANY OWNED']], dtype=object)

Comment: Right, for text label data, you have to use LabelEncoder, sorry.